# Flask / SqlAlchemy / Graphene - how to query an object from DB and change value?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, graphene-python

I wish to open a GraphQL mutation endpoint where an id and string is sent in. This would then gather the item based on the ID and change a value in the object, and save the change in the item in the DB.

It would look something like this:

```
Query SomeMutation{
ExampleMutation(input: {id: 1, Status: "Something"}){
    ExampleObject{
        id
        Status
     }
 }
}
```

I currently have the following setup:

(Schema.py)

```
class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    ExampleMutation = ExampleMutation.Field()
```

(Schema_ExampleObject.py)

```
class Captcha(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleObjectModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
```

(ExampleMutation.py)

```
class Attributes:
    id = graphene.Int(description="Id")
    status = graphene.String(description="Status")


class ExampleMutationInput(graphene.InputObjectType, Attributes):
    pass


class ExampleSolution(graphene.Mutation):
    ExampleObject= graphene.Field(lambda: ExampleObject, description="Example Object")

    class Arguments:
        input = ExampleMutationInput(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, input):
        data = input

        # **** Here I want to query an item from the DB based on the ID and change a value in it, then save it in the DB and return the new object to the GraphQL. ****

        return ExampleMutation(exampleobject=exampleobject)
```

I looked up at solutions online and I saw library calls that would work in the following manner:

```
item = ExampleObject.query.filter(blablanla)
```

But the Object doesn't have such functions as "Query" so I'm left confused.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the correct way of performing the operation:

```
 query = ExameObject.get_query(info=info)
 query = query.filter(ExampleObject.id == data.id)
 example_object = query.first()
```